# My Computer can only take one screenshot. It will not allow me to take another screenshot unless I restart it first

Tags: windows, screenshot

Basically exactly what the title says - my computer will take one screenshot, then fail to be able to take any screenshots (the darkened screen with the ss options will not even show up) until the next time I restart my computer. I usually use the win+shift+s shortcut to take screenshots on windows, but I still have the same problem even when I open up and try to manually take a screenshot from snip and sketch. I have already tried to reset Snip and sketch, which did nothing, and even when I changed my settings so that the print screen button could also take ss, the same issue occured. Does anyone know the possible problem and how to fix it?

Note: I am not much of a computer person. If you have an solution/suggestion, please try to explain it so that a person with a normal amount of tech knowledge would understand.

Comment: you can use https://recorder.easeus.com/screenshot.html to take multiple screenshots with good quality. It really helped

Answer (score 0):

Snip 'n Sketch works fine (multiple times without restarting). So also does SnagIt (I use the latter most of the time).

Steps to try:

**(A) DISM /SFC**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. (2) DISM.exe /Online
> /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup (3) DISM.exe /Online
> /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth (4) SFC /SCANNOW (5) Restart when all
> the above is complete and test.

**(B) If (A) does not fix the problem, try a Windows 10 Repair Install.**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

Note that a Repair Install, Keep Everything will not fix a damaged User Profile.

**(C) Damaged Windows User Profile:**

If Repair Install does not fix the issue, then make a new User Profile to test for a damaged profile.

If you need to replace a damaged Windows User Profile, proceed carefully as follows:

```
(a) Make a new Windows User Account and make it a member of Administrators. 
(b) Log into the new Windows Account.
(c) Copy documents, email and everything you need to the same folders in C:\Temp (make C:\Temp).
(d) Delete the damaged user (System Tools, Profiles).
(e) Delete the user account (Settings, Accounts).
(f) Restart.
(g) Make your new User Account.
(h) Restore your Documents and Email.
```

Often it is just as simple to back up thoroughly and reinstall Windows than to work through replacing a User Profile.

Comment: Or just use Greenshot

Comment: Yes but that does not solve the built in Snip ‘n Sketch issue which really should be fixed

Comment: If you use Greenshot fixing that issue isn't a priority imho.